# How to use linq contains like %[0-9]%

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a Linq query that uses `like %[0-9]%` from sql-server.

This is my start:

```
string[] partNumbers = new string[] 
{ 
    "India", "US","UK", "Australia","Germany", "1", "7", "9" , "50", "A1"
};

var result = partNumbers.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

How to write a linq query in c# which contains like "%[0-9]%"

This is the expected output:

> 1
>   7
>   9
>   50
>   A1

Comment: First write a method that performs the operation on a single value in your sequence.  Then it should be a very simple matter of looking through the given linq operators to see how to apply that operation on the entire sequence to get all of the values where that given condition is met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Regular expression

```
var result = partNumbers.Where(x => Regex.Match(x, "\\d+").Success);
```

Answer (score 1):

This may helps:

```
string[] partNumbers = new string[] 
{ 
    "India", "US","UK", "Australia","Germany", "1", "7", "9" , "50", "A1"
};

char[] numbers = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

var result = partNumbers.Where(i=>i.Intersect(numbers).Any()).ToList();
```

**Result:**

```
1
7
9
50
A1
```

**EDIT:** if you are looking for `LIKE` operator in SQL you can use the [SqlMethods.Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: don't we have anything like sql like operator

Comment: sqlmethods is not working, I had included the following namespace even  System.Data.Linq.SqlClient

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: `SqlMethods.Like` only works for Linq2Sql queries, not linq2object.